# How best to store game config variables in java

Tags: java

I'm writing a small java game and am storing global game settings in a class structure like the one below:

```
public class Globals {
    public static int tileSize = 16;
    public static String screenshotDir = "..\\somepath\\..";
    public static String screenshotNameFormat = "gameNamexxx.png";
    public static int maxParticles = 300;
    public static float gravity = 980f;
    // etc
}
```

While this is very convenient to work with I'd like to know if this is the accepted pattern.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Store it in a `.properties` file.

**config.properties**

```
tile.size=16
screenshot.dir=..\\somepath\\..
```

**Reading it**

```
// Make sure this happens only the first time you start your application
Properties properties = new Properties();
// You can use FileInputStream, ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream or a reader too
properties.load(...)
```

**Using it**

```
int tileSize = Integer.valueOf(properties.getProperty("tile.size"));
String screenshotDir = properties.getProperty("screenshot.dir");
```

To simplify things, and to keep your changes minimal, you can also do something like this:

```
public class Globals {
    private static final Properties properties = new Properties();

    static {
        // do the loading here
    }

    public static final int TILE_SIZE = 
        Integer.valueOf(properties.getProperty("tile.size"));
    public static final String SCREENSHOT_DIR = 
        properties.getProperty("screenshot.dir");
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Personaly, I'd rather store them in POJO and (de)serialize to XML file with some XStream library. Much more convenient than reading properties. Too lazy to write the separate answer though.

Comment: +1 for properties: they're dead simple, everyone understands them and they're end-user editable.

Comment: In case when you want to hide properties from malefactor, using class with static vars seems more preferable than .properties file in terms of security. Class still can be decompiled, but that`s more complicated task.

Answer (score 1):

If it really is a small application, it will do. It's not ideal but there's no point bringing in too much sophistication on a small scale.

But read those values from a properties file.